# Sharing with windows pc

Tags: windows, sharing

I connected my Ubuntu laptop to Windows PC through lan cable to transfer file from PC to laptop.i installed samba on Ubuntu. Then  the opened network, in it I clicked on windows network but it is not opening. Showing message  unable to access location:failed to retrieve share list from server

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Does your connection work? Try it with ping from each side.

Comment: Sorry but I am new on Ubuntu.  what is ping

Comment: ping is a command available in Windows cmd and Linux terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T). With `ping ip-address` or `ping name` you can test your connection. More information on this command with `man ping`.